# INNER JOIN in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

There are my two tables:

Table name: **FRIENDS**

```
+-------+---------+---------+-------------------+
|  id   |  firstName   |  lastName  | city      |
+-------+--------------+------------+-----------+
| 1     | dudi         | edri       | london    |
| 2     | maor         | azulay     | madrid    |
| 3     | batel        | azulay     | tel aviv  |
| 4     | nir          | cohen      | barcelona |
| 5     | evia         | perez      | miami     |
| 6     | neria        | perez      | new-york  | 
| 7     | nevo         | kakoun     | roma      |
+-------+---------+---------+-------------------+
```

Table name: **ORDERS**

```
+-------+---------+---------+-----------------+
|  id   |  firstName   |  amount  | status    |
+-------+--------------+----------+-----------+
| 1     | dudi         | 5684     | shipped   |
| 2     | maor         | 4896     | shipped   |
| 3     | batel        | 2496     | delay     |
+-------+--------------+----------+-----------+
```

my question is:
I want the friends that have no order.
The answer:

```
| 4     | nir          | cohen      | barcelona |
| 5     | evia         | perez      | miami     |
| 6     | neria        | perez      | new-york  | 
| 7     | nevo         | kakoun     | roma      |
+-------+---------+---------+-------------------+
```

how i wrote the query with inner join.
Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't use firstName in `ORDERS` as Foreign Key. It doesn't make any sense

Comment: Yes - the foreign key should reference the primary key

Comment: the column to do inner join is: id

Comment: Correct. So fix that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use `firstName` in `ORDERS` as Foreign Key. The foreign key should reference the primary key. Use `ID` from `FRIENDS` like:

Table name: **ORDERS**

```
+-------+---------+---------+-----------------+
|  id   |  friendID    |  amount  | status    |
+-------+--------------+----------+-----------+
| 1     | 1            | 5684     | shipped   |
| 2     | 2            | 4896     | shipped   |
| 3     | 3            | 2496     | delay     |
+-------+--------------+----------+-----------+
```

And query using `LEFT OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT f.*
FROM FRIENDS f
LEFT JOIN  ORDERS o
  ON f.ID = o.friendID
WHERE o.ID IS NULL;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/400653)**</kbd>

Another possibility is to use `correlated subquery`:

```
SELECT f.*
FROM FRIENDS f
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM orders o
                  WHERE o.friendID = f.ID);
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/400654)**</kbd>

---

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE friends(
  id        INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY     -- you can add AUTO_INCREMENT if needed
   ...
);

CREATE TABLE orders(
  id       INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY     
  ,friendID INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,FOREIGN KEY (friendID) REFERENCES friends(id)
  ...
);
```